# Actual number of records in SOQL when Limit is used

Tags: soql

I am using LIMIT in the SOQL query.
When the results size is 60, I am displaying a warning message saying, upto 60 agreements are shown, please refine your search.

```
 String finalQuery = 'select Id,SALE_REP_QTY__c,SERV_REP_QTY__c, Name,Customer__r.Name, MAX_GROUP_INFRC_LIVES_QTY__c,Assign_Source_System__c,(select Id, Name from Agreement_Products__r WHERE Name in (\'LTD\',\'STD\' ,\'LIFE\', \'AD&D\',\'DENT\',\'GLTC\') and Product_status__c = \'ACTVE\'),'+
                                       +'(select Id,AGRMT_ID__c, RLSHP_TYPE_CD__c, REP_CR_PCT__c, REP_USER_ID__r.Name,UNUM_ID__c from AGRMT_REPs__r where RLSHP_TYPE_CD__c in (\'SALESREP\', \'SERVREP\') and (REP_AGRMT_END_DT__c = null or REP_AGRMT_END_DT__c > :todayDate ) and REP_AGRMT_SORCE_SYST_CD__c = \'MKIE\' and REP_AGRMT_BEGIN_DT__c <= :todayDate ) from Agreement__c ' + 
                                        'where Id IN:agIdSet and Agreement_Status__c != \'TRMNT\' and Assign_Source_System__c in (\'GRASN\',\'POLAR\' ,\'PRISM\', \'CLONE\') and ((SALE_REP_QTY__c != 0 AND SERV_REP_QTY__c!=0) OR (SALE_REP_QTY__c = 0 AND SERV_REP_QTY__c != 0 ) OR (SALE_REP_QTY__c != 0 AND SERV_REP_QTY__c = 0 )) order by  ' + sortFullExp+' LIMIT 60';


                agreementList = Database.query(finalQuery);

                  if(agreementList.size() == 60){

                  ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING,'Upto 60 Agreements shown, Please refine your search');
                       ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 

                  }
```

Now I want to change the warning message to, "Upto 60 agreements are shown out of total number, please refine your search."

Now my question is, how do I get the actual number without querying twice?

Comment: I think you mean "more than", not "up to"

Comment: You are imposing a limit on the query and expecting to know the total number of records with out doing extra query. It is a bit difficult with out querying since there are lot of conditions need to be obeyed before getting the total number.

So I suggest you to do an extra query with all the conditions but donot pull the whole date. you query should look like this.

Select count(Id) from ObjectName where (dynamically generated conditions)

Answer (score 1):

Do an additional query using exactly the same WHERE clause, but either without a limit or with a much higher limit, just to get the record count.

```
Integer recordCount = Database.query(
    'select Count() from Agreement__c'
    + commonWhereClause
    + ' limit 5001');
```

If `recordCount == 5001`, display "more than 5000 records".

If you are confident that you will never have to worry about governor limits, then you don't have to use `limit` on the count query.